# Scanner и List как построить ввод данных из консоли с записью в массив

Tags: java, arraylist, scanner

В общем вот мой код:
сначала определяю кол-во эл-тов, потом пытаюсь каждому записать строку из консоли, что-то идет не так. Прошу разъяснений.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int employeeNumber = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("en=" + employeeNumber);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < employeeNumber; i++) {
            list.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("s=" + list.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: А что идёт "не так"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/); [Scanner не считывает строку после `nextInt()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/); [Не сканируется строка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345986/)

Comment: Ещё дубликаты: [Посчитать зарплату для каждого из сотрудников. Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345651/); [Не работает case со string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479743/); [Почему программа пропускает строку? в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983344/); [Компилятор пропускает String переменная = scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303277/)... десятки подобных вопросов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После ввода размера списка методом `nextInt()` в буфере остаётся пустая строка и символ, означающий переход на новую строку. Метод `nextLine()` работает таким образом, что считывает всё, что было во введённой строке до символа перехода на новую строку, и затем переходит далее.

Когда вы вызываете этот метод для ввода элементов списка в цикле, сначала он считывает ту самую пустую строку, и только затем начинает считывать вновь вводимые данные. То есть, в той программе, которую вы привели, первым элементом списка будет пустая строка.

Для того, чтобы работа была корректной, можно, например, после ввода размера списка просто вызвать метод `nextLine()`, чтобы он прочитал эту ненужную пустую строку и далее ввод был таким, какой ожидается.

Answer (score -1):

Сделай:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= employeeNumber; i++) {
            list.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
```

Тогда у тебя лист на 1 значение больше, но результат корректный. Вся проблема в том, что ты не ожидаешь в коде начала строк, и у тебя строка en= сразу записывается как пустая, если ее показывать позже, то все ок.

Comment: А зачем нужна пустая строка в начале списка?  Какой-то неправильный костыль получается.